# Add button clear value ion-datetime in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic3

I want create a ion-date time with three button : cancel , done and clear. so I custom in here:

[Add button clear data ion-datetime](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5bcino?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

I want if date is chose I can click Clear in modal date picker to remove value same when click button Clear Data.
How I can do it?
Thank every one

Answer (score 2):

I’m using :

I’ve added a custom button to a ionic-datetime

```
<ion-datetime
    formControlName="myDateCustom"
    [pickerOptions]="customPickerOption">
</ion-datetime>
```

and ts.

```
customPickerOption = {
    buttons: [{
    text: 'Clear',
       handler: () => this.myForm.controls['myDateCustom'].setValue(null)
}]
```